# Kafka Listener failed to start in spring project

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

In my spring project i am getting this error at server startup

```html
Jun 28, 2020 3:54:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.determineInferredType(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:539)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListenerInstance(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:185)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:144)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:423)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:408)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:183)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:129)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:164)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:158)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using spring version - 4.3.5
And kafka version - 2.2.0.RELEASE

Can you please help here what i am doing wrong
I have tried degrading spring version to 4.2.0 but it results in the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your spring-context and spring-text are the same version?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-text</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring.context - i am using 4.1.7.RELEASE